# Failed to resolve: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0`

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

### What is the error in android studio ??

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    //adding glid library
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try using updating your google play service library.

Comment: All is updated ..

Comment: @SajjadAli Check my answer below. The appindexing lib has moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appindexing library has moved to firebase. Add below to your app's build.gradle file :)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0 is deprecated, the only solution is to bump the version to the latest - 11.0.2